# Ctrl-S Search Function

Tags: search

A few months ago I learned that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> would "search" within any page that I was on.

Recently, probably after an update,this has changed to become "Save to File"  and trying it again today  It has no evident function at all.

Any clue about how to restore the Search function?
Can it be done in Unity-Tweaks?

Comment: Try Ctrl-F maybe?

Comment: That's it Grammargeek! Thank-You.

Comment: Can you mark mine as the answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> should do what you want.